# AdCreativesV2 Batch GET API returns 400 BAD REQUEST - "Cannot process request involving multiple routing entities"

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, spring-social-linkedin

I am making API requests to a url like this to access AdCreatives API:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2?ids=List(123,456,789)
(not the exact ids, but you get the idea)

Depending on the IDs used in the call, sometimes this works as expected, and sometimes I get a 400 error code response with the message "Cannot process request involving multiple routing entities"

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I assume I can't make a request that includes all of these ids at once, but is there a way to tell which ids are causing the problem? This could help me group similar IDs successfully to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you are using `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` in the `header`?
For example, for me in python this looks like

```
headers['X-Restli-Protocol-Version'] = '2.0.0'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This is mentioned on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives?tabs=curl#batch-get-ad-creatives)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Creatives belong to the same account.
[Based on LinkedIn's new error messages documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/error-messages), the new error message that will replace the "Cannot process request involving multiple routing entities" message is indicating that the ad account of the Creative_ids is not identical:

> Entities should have the same ad account in batch update and batch partial update request.